# Flutter Text To Speech - ERROR

Tags: flutter, dart

estoy intentando que un bucle vaya nombrando diferentes números aleatorios mediante text to speech con flutter y dart.
La cosa es que si introduzco un valor de 5 cifras solo me lee la primera y la ultima correctamente.
El resto repite el último número de la lista, es decir, pongo un ejemplo.
Números [ 1,2,3,4,5 ]
Vocea 1, 5, 5, 5, 5 en vez de 1,2,3,4,5 pero si en el bucle introduzco un print(numero[i]) este imprime correctamente 1,2,3,4,5.

Puede ser que el bucle se ejecute tan rápido que sobre escriba el valor de la variable que se le pasa a la función de text to speech o que puede ser? Alguien sabe como solucionarlo?

Dejo el código de las funciones que utilizo

```
void generarNumerosAleatorios(String text) {
    var numeros = int.parse(text);
    var diez = 10;
    var numeros_finales = pow(diez, numeros);
    var numOk = Random().nextInt(numeros_finales.toInt());
    var numLetters = numOk.toString();
    speak(numLetters);
  }

  speak(String text) async {
    var splitNums = text.split("");
    await flutterTts.setLanguage("es-ES");
    await flutterTts.setPitch(1);
    for (var numeroLista in splitNums) {
      print(numeroLista);
      flutterTts.speak(numeroLista);
    }
  }
```

Gracias de antemano por vuestra ayuda

Answer (score 1):

Tiene que esperar a que se complete cada flutterTts.speak().

```
void generarNumerosAleatorios(String text) {
  var numeros = int.parse(text);
  var diez = 10;
  var numeros_finales = pow(diez, numeros);
  var numOk = Random().nextInt(numeros_finales.toInt());
  var numLetters = numOk.toString();
  speak(numLetters);
}

speak(String text)  async {
  var splitNums = text.split("");
  await flutterTts.setLanguage("es-ES");
  await flutterTts.setPitch(1);
  for (var numeroLista in splitNums) {
    print(numeroLista);
    await flutterTts.speak(numeroLista);
  }
}
```

Comment: He probado como decías pero aun así no iba. Entonces he cogido al idea y viendo un poco la información de internet he probado con "await flutterTts.awaitSpeakCompletion(true);" y poniendo "generarNumerosAleatorios" como ASYNC para poder llamar a la función _speak con await.
Gracias por la ayuda !!!

Answer (score 0):

Lo tengo, he tenido que poner como ASYNC y con AWAIT las funciones dentro del bucle y las funciones que llaman a fluttertts.
Pongo el código:

```
 generarNumerosAleatorios(String text) async {
    var numeros = int.parse(text);
    var diez = 10;
    var numeros_finales = pow(diez, numeros);
    var numOk = Random().nextInt(numeros_finales.toInt());
    var numLetters = numOk.toString();
    var splitNums = numLetters.split("");
    for (var numeroLista in splitNums) {
      await _speak(numeroLista);
    }
  }

  _speak(String text) async {
    await flutterTts.setLanguage("es-ES");
    await flutterTts.setPitch(1);
    await flutterTts.awaitSpeakCompletion(true);
    await flutterTts.speak(text);
  }
```

Muchas graciasc por la ayuda !!